# Entity Framework Code First: The number of properties in the Dependent and Principal Roles in a relationship constraint must be identical

Tags: entity-framework, foreign-keys, composite-primary-key

Database build error:

> One or more validation errors were detected during model generation:
>
> Key_Authorities_Source_Key_Authorities_Target: : **The number of
> properties in the Dependent and Principal Roles in a relationship
> constraint must be identical.**

Key Class:

```
[Table("Keys")]
public class Key
{
    [Key, Column(Order = 0)]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Key, Column(Order = 1)]
    public int OwnedByFId { get; set; }

    [Key, Column(Order = 2)]
    public int OwnedByUId { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public string Description { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("Id"), Column(Order = 1)]
    public virtual ICollection<KeyAuthorities> Authorities { get; set; }
}
```

Key Authorities Class:

```
[Table("Key_Auths")]
public class KeyAuthorities
{
    [Key, Column(Order = 0)]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    
    [Key, Column(Order = 1)]
    public int KeyId { get; set; }
    
    public int DoorId { get; set; }

    public int VehicleId { get; set; }

    public int GateId { get; set; }
}
```

Why doesn't this set this foreign key?

Comment: This model can't work. EF doesn't allow `ICollection` (non-generic) in a navigation property.

Answer (score 1):

The error message is actually telling you that the **number** of properties don't match. This is because your *Key* class is uniquely identified by 3 properties (the 3 PK that you define: `Id`, `OwnedByFId` and `OwnedByUId`), but you're trying to define a Foreign Key to your *Key* Class using only the `Id`.

You must set all the PKs on your foreign class:

```
[Table("Key_Auths")]
public class KeyAuthorities
{
    [Key, Column(Order = 0)]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Key, Column(Order = 1)]
    [ForeignKey("Id, OwnedByFId, OwnedByUId")]
    public int KeyId { get; set; }

    public int DoorId { get; set; }
    
    public int VehicleId { get; set; }

    public int GateId { get; set; }
}
```

Notice that I added the data annotation `[ForeignKey("Id, OwnedByFId, OwnedByUId")]`.

Answer (score 0):

```
// error message is basically telling that you have 
// not configured the keys and their order properly in "Keys" table

public class Keys {
    [Key, Column(Order = 0)]
    public int Key_1 { get; set; }

    [Key, Column(Order = 1)]
    public int Key_2 { get; set; }

    // order is important here as defined in "KeyAuthorities" table
    [ForeignKey("KeyAuthorities", Column(Order = 0)]
    public int KeyAuthorities_Key_1 { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("KeyAuthorities", Column(Order = 1)]
    public int KeyAuthorities_Key_2 { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection KeyAuthorities { get; set; }
}

public class KeyAuthorities {
    [Key, Column(Order = 0)]
    public int KeyAuthorities_Key_1 { get; set; }

    [Key, Column(Order = 1)]
    public int KeyAuthorities_Key_2 { get; set; }

}
```